# Prevent countdown going into negatives

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nstimer, foundation

I've created a countdown timer and it works great.. but when it reaches zero it continues counting down.. so it shows -1, -2, -3 etc. How do I prevent it from doing this?

This is my code from the implementation file..

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)start {

    myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)stop {
    [myTicker invalidate];
}

-(IBAction)reset {
    time.text = @"0";
}

-(void)showActivity {
    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime -1;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
}
```

I'm guessing that I'm missing some code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix is to change:

```
int newTime = currentTime - 1;
```

into:

```
int newTime = (currentTime > 0) ? currentTime - 1 : 0;
```

That will stop the countdown timer from going below zero. If that's all you need, that should suffice.

---

It *won't* turn off the timer or execute an action when it reaches zero. For that, you'll need to add something like the following block after that line above:

```
if ((currentTime > 0) && (newTime ==0)) {
    // optionally turn off timer
    fireZeroEvent ();
}
```

and provide the `fireZeroEvent()` function to do whatever you need to do.

I say *optionally* turn off the timer since you may want to leave it running so you can restart the countdown by just be setting `time.text` without have to recreate the timer.

For that reason, the `fireZeroEvent()` is only called on the transition from 1 to 0, not every time the timer fires after it reaches zero.

Comment: @user1253207: sorry, I mistyped - that first `:` should have been a `?` - try it again.

Comment: @user1253207: I'll add that unless you have a specific reason to keep the timer going, you really should stop it. paxdiablo's code does not stop it; you need to add code for that yourself.